# Migrating BLOB data from MS SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

There is a remote MS SQL Server that I have read access to. It has thousands of pictures in a BLOB- one of the many problems being that they are in datatype image.

I want to transfer all of that BLOB data to a local MySQL BLOB. I have tried using php mssql_connect (which is pretty broken) to no avail, I have also hunted down a copy of textcopy.exe; however, textcopy.exe only gives me the data as a photo-- not as the raw BLOB/HEX data. What is the best way of doing this, so that I can run it whenever I want to bring over more data as it is added to the MS SQL Server DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Data Import tool in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Select an ODBC data import format, configure ODBC connection to MS SQL database, and try to migrate data into MySQL.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried exporting that under the mssql management console and it's a POS. This worked perfectly. Mad props =)