# Store MSSQL blob data to MySQL blob data

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, blob

I need to use a mssql database to build a web application in php/mysql. Mssql has images stored in blob datatype. I don't want to use external tools as described here [Migrating BLOB data from MS SQL Server to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528267/migrating-blob-data-from-mssql-to-mysql). I want to store data through php script but i have a problem in storing the mssql data to mysql data so that i can display images from my php application. Everytime i tried to store data from mssql to mysql it show query error. What should i do to store the blob data to mysql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do that using PHP. However, there are few important considerations:

1. You must use prepared statements and bind your blob to correct type as [described here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php)
2. If your images are bigger than 1MB (default limit), you have to tweak both client and server configuration to increase [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) to be 16 or even 32MB.