# What is the difference between image(SQL Server) and longblob(MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, image, blob

SQL Server Image Table

```
CREATE TABLE "SqlServerTable" (
    "id" INT NOT NULL,
    "image" IMAGE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

MySQL Image Table

```
CREATE TABLE `MySqlTable` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL,
    `image` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

What is the difference between `image` and `longblob`?

How can convert data from `image` type in SQL Server to `blob` type in MySQL?

When I copy data from SQL Server to MySQL, does not show any image with this
`file_put_contents('2xx.jpg',$MySqlTable['image']);`?

I have do special processing on image type SQL Server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528267/migrating-blob-data-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql

Comment: No,i can transform data from sql server to mysql,but when transform data from sqlserver to mysql does not show image because say image binary is not valid fomrmat

Comment: this will help you make a migration in a valid way. you shouldn't copy the image field content to longblob in mysql

Comment: I think you can use a converter program, and don't do it directly

Comment: @BehzadHassani How can do it?and this program What to do؟

Comment: @chatkai I think you can make a little multi thread program to migrate your data, you can use C# for multi thread purpose and it's libraries for connecting to MySQL

Comment: IMHO, you can use storing URL File Links instead - I think this can be a solution for storing an image in multiple DB ;).

Comment: [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3748/4519059) ;).

Answer (score 2):

> **[BLOB in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)**
>   BLOB values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have no character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values.
>   The four BLOB types are `TINYBLOB`, `BLOB`, `MEDIUMBLOB`, and `LONGBLOB`. These differ only in the maximum length of the values they can hold.
>   MySQL Connector/ODBC defines BLOB values as **`LONGVARBINARY`**.

> **[image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)**
>   Variable-length binary data from 0 through 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) bytes.
>   `image` data type will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Use **`varbinary(max)`** instead.
>   [Microsoft research: To BLOB or Not To BLOB](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525)

IMHO, both are a set of binary data and difference is about how each DBMS stores that set of binary data.
I think a better solution to avoid processing over images, streams and so on is to store URL File  Links if there is not any advantage of using in table file data.